# Upsert local file into remote MongoDB with Ansible

Tags: mongodb, ansible

I'm trying to construct an Ansible playbook that upserts some records from a JSON file into a MongoDB collection running on the remote host.

I could copy the JSON file to the remote host, run `mongoimport`, then delete the file. But I was contemplating doing this with two tasks, one to read the file locally, and one to upsert remotely:

```yaml
- name: Read users collection entries
  local_action:
    module: ansible.builtin.command
    cmd: cat files/mongo/users.js
  register: users_collection

- name: Upsert into mongo
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: >-
      mongoimport
        --db mydb
        --collection users
        --jsonArray
        --mode upsert
        --upsertFields username
    stdin: "{{ users_collection.stdout }}"
  failed_when: result.stdout.find("0 document(s) failed to import.") != -1
```

However I get odd errors from `mongoimport`, like:

```
Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'r' in literal Timestamp (expecting 'i')
0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

There are no timestamps in my document, so I'm not sure what is causing this. I copied the file to the host manually and `mongoimport` ran fine.

If I change the `mongoimport` command in the playbook to `cat`, so that I can see the input the command is receiving, it also looks correct.

I also don't know why `mongoimport` is saying "0 document(s) failed to import" if one of them hits an error.

Comment: Is your json file an array (starts with `[`) ?

Comment: Yes, it's an array of documents to upsert. As I said, it is accepted when I run `mongoimport` manually.

Comment: Can you import it using `--file files/mongo/users.js` instead of piping it from `cat` ?

Comment: The error comes from the json parser: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/cbdf89967b93b03a915e87d1c7694f77671c4769/common/json/timestamp.go#L23 Once it reads "T" character, it assumes it's a timestamp and expects the next character to be "i". Apparently the cat sent something starting with "Tr" in the first line, or at least it's what ansible outputs to stdout of mongoimport, so unless you want to dig down, just upload the file to the remote and import it with --file option.